# How do I make everything on this page centered and fully responsive for all browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

Link to my website: http://foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/contact.php

I am having trouble with my contact page. I want the entire thing to be centered and responsive no matter what the screen size (even if you resize your window to the tiniest possible width). NOTE: Leave the large/desktop screen alone that is how I want it to look unless you find a way to make the form width bigger and responsive. I attempted to make the entire page centered on medium and small screens. However, as the page shrinks, the center attribute measurements are off a bit. The reason for this was that some had to be different so that it looked good for older browsers. The social icons are giving me trouble too. Is there any way to make the entire thing centered for all devices and browsers? I tried my best with the measurements. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are my problems that I wish to fix:

Firefox:
        On medium pages, the form is going out of bounds.
        On small pages, the form is shrinking when the page is small.
        On small pages, social icons are messed up.
        On medium and small pages, the form is not centered evenly.

IE 7:
        On medium pages and small pages, social icons are messed up.
        On small pages, the form is going out of bounds.
        Form is not shrinking on small screens.
        On medium and small pages, the form is not centered evenly.

IE 8:
        On small pages, the form is shrinking.
        On medium and small pages, the form is not centered evenly.
        Social icons are not as bad.

HTML:

```
<section>

            <div id='main_section'>
                <div id = "center">
                <div id='details_section'> 
                <br/>

                    <h2> Stay in touch </h2><br/>
                    <p>I love getting feedback regarding all my projects, works, and services. You can use the quick contact form to leave a message, comments and questions.</p><br/>
                    <p>Your name and e-mail address are never shared, I just use them when I need to get back to you.</p><br/>


                    <h2> Social networks </h2><br/>
                    <div id = "center_icons">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lenny.pfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" style="margin:1px;"></a> 

                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/113122168458946246215/posts" target="_blank"><img src="images/google-plus.png" alt="google plus" style="margin:1px;"></a>

                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/leonard-pfautsch/53/b34/1a2" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" style="margin:1px;"></a>

                        <a href="https://github.com/LeonardPfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/github.png" alt="github" style="margin:1px;"></a>
                    </div>
                <br/>

                </div>
                </div>

                <div id = "center">
                <div id='contact_section'>
                    <form method='POST' action='contact.php'>
                    <span class='label'>Name:</span><br/>
                    <input type='text' class='textfield' name='name' size='50' maxlength='50'><br/>
                    <span class='label'>Email:</span><br/>
                    <input type='text' class='textfield' name='email' size='50' maxlength='50'><br/>
                    <span class='label'>Subject:</span><br/>
                    <input type='text' class='textfield' name='subject' size='50' maxlength='50'><br/>
                    <span class='label'>Message:</span><br/>
                    <textarea rows='5' cols='50' name='message' id='textarea' maxlength='500'></textarea><br/>
                    <input type='submit' value='Send' id='submit' name='action'> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </section>
```

Main CSS:

```
#details_section {

    max-width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;


}


#contact_section {
    max-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    margin-right: 0px;

    margin-top:20px;
    padding:20px; /*Make this smaller for 100% responsiveness*/
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #272727; 
    float:right;
}


#submit {
    padding:0px 8px;
    background:#c4c4c4; 
    width:115px;
    height:33px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #8d8d8d;
    max-width:100%;
}
#submit:hover {
    background:#a8a8a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.button input {
padding:0px 8px;
    background:#c4c4c4; 
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #8d8d8d;
    margin:1px;
    max-width:100%;
}

div.button input:hover {
background:#a8a8a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Large screens:

```
#details_section {
    width:320px;
}
```

Medium Screens:

```
#center{
width: 465px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#center_icons{
width: 228px; /*this value is changing for IE and chrome*/
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#contact_section {
width:450px;

}

#details_section {
    width: 450px;
    text-align:justify;
}

#details_section h2 {
    width: 450px;
    text-align:center;

}

textarea, input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
}

textarea{
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Small Screens:

```
#center{
width: 465px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#center_icons{
width: 228px; /*this value is changing for IE and chrome*/
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#contact_section {
width:450px;

}

#details_section {
    width: 450px;
    text-align:justify;
}

#details_section h2 {
    width: 450px;
    text-align:center;

}

textarea, input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
}

textarea{
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: It seems like you're asking for help on multiple issues. Perhaps you can isolate one problem at at time, unless you suspect all these problems are symptomatic of the same cause--if so, please tell us what you know and what you've done.

Comment: I have tried incorporating measurements that I saw would be best fit for all browsers (you can see this on the medium and small css I pretty much cut the medium css in half for small screens. However, when I do that the page is not fully centered anymore. It is off because I tried fixing it for older browsers. Now the whole thing is not 100% centered like I want. I also don't know how to make the form fully responsive since it sometimes goes outside of the white and into the blue or it merges to the left and it is not centered anymore. I don't know why.

Comment: I would assume it is all one issue since it impacts all browsers depending on any changes that I make.

Comment: If you can't find a way, You can always use the <center></center> tag's but I would recommend not doing that if possible.

Comment: Yes I do know that. I wish I could use that but unfortunately my page will have an HTML5 validation error because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an Element Inspector to get the look just right on your page. All modern browsers include them. It seems like all you need are little CSS tweaks here and there. For example, you can set your inputs to a different width in the small and medium layouts (line 116 change to `width:90%`).

It's important to gain a proper understanding of box-sizing and how that works. It seems like compounded margins and padding are what's causing elements to overflow. http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Yes you seem to have the right idea. I have tried this and it is fixing a lot of my problems. I am currently working on this now and constantly updating the page so you can see my changes. And can you perhaps input the code from the line you say I do not know which one you are referring to.

Comment: I mean in your stylesheet.

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note, you might want to consider posting your site to /r/design_critiques on reddit. They would have some good input for you.